# Coding collaboratively for the web

Tags: php, python, web-services, versioning

In the past I've done the coding-part of my web-projects mostly by myself. Now, as we are a team working on some project, be it python or php or ..., is there some simple versioning system to use?

My hoster doesn't seem to support any kind of this sort. On the other hand, I feel it is too early to start renting a whole server in this phase of the project just to be able to install a versioning system.

Any simple ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Mercurial](https://www.mercurial-scm.org). If your hosting has ssh and python support, you can run Mercurial on it.

**UPDATE**: By the way, you don't need a hosting to run Mercurial - it's distributed and works without any servers. If you still want to have a repository on your hosting server - you can have it if your hoster supports ssh and python

**UPDATE**: http://bitbucket.org - fantastic mercurial hosting, allows 1 private repository and unlimited public repositories for free

Answer (score 2):

See:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59791/free-online-private-svn-repositories
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146505/can-someone-recommend-a-reliable-cvs-or-svn-hosting-service
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111292/free-version-control-services

Comment: sorry.. I suck at searching... ;)

Answer (score 1):

http://github.com
Anonymous Sourcecode Hosting, Repository...

Comment: And you can use Mercurial with git as well.

Answer (score 0):

Github and the others are free for open source projects only.
However, Xp-dev is free as in free beer even to commercial ones. http://www.xp-dev.com/